# localhost/laravel/public/post Not Found

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to the laravel framework. I started a tutorial video on tuts, and followed the directions exactly. I setup laravel and was able to access localhost/laravel/public just fine. I even changed routes.php and was still able to access localhost/laravel/public. However, the next step in the tutorial was to create a new Route. my new Route looks like this

> Route::get('post', 'PostController@show');

I then created a new controller called `PostController`. The file looks like this:

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController
{
    public function show()
    {
        return View::make('post.show');
    }
}
```

Next, the tutorial asked me to create a `show.php` in a new directory called "post". Then when I access `localhost/laravel/public/post` the "show.php" should appear. Instead I receive an error that says

> "The requested URL /laravel/public/post was not found on this server"

I am running Apache/2.4.9 (win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Once again, I followed the exact instructions from tutsplus.

Comment: What is the `DocumentRoot` of your vhost setup to point to? What happens if you try to visit `localhost/laravel/post` instead? Also, can you post the link to the tutorial you're trying to follow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't access URL in Laravel routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133517/cant-access-url-in-laravel-routes)

Comment: here is a link to the tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/new-course-getting-started-with-laravel-4--cms-22162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check wheather the `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` files are set properly.You need to make sure if document root is pointing to the laravels public directory.

Please have a check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458080/the-requested-url-projectname-users-was-not-found-on-this-server-laravel)